# Is there python module which is same as dlmFilter in R

Tags: python, r

I have two datasets, one is the reference and the other is the real measurement. I want to predict the measurement data using the reference. I found the R function dlmFilter that can realize it. I create a dlm model using the reference dataset using the dlmModReg function. Then I apply this model to the measurements dataset using dlmFilter or dlmSmooth functions to get the filtered or smoothed measurements data.

```
in R:
mod<-dlmModReg(reference,dW=c(sigmaZ,sigmaZ),m0=c(0,1))
FilterRes=dlmFilter(measurements,mod)
```

I try to do it in Python. I found the pydlm function which can build the dlm model and reference dataset.

```
in Python:
from pydlm import dlm, trend, seasonality, dynamic, autoReg, longSeason
myDLM = dlm(reference)
```

But how can I apply the myDLM model to the measurements????

Thank you in advance